# How will you show data to modal?

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I would like to know your opinion regarding on showing data to modal.

Lets say for example: 
I have a button that will open a modal and get data from database. What I did is every time I opened the modal it will always query to the database which causes my system/application loads slower and slower. I would like to know your opinion on what is the best approach in solving this problem?

Any answers will be much appreciated.

NOTE: I AM USING BOOTSTRAP AND NATIVE PHP

Comment: It really depends on how often the button is clicked, how big is the query your app needs to do every time. I don't really have problems making ajax calls when I need modals.

Comment: I tried clicking the button multiple times maybe 15x and my app/system became slower. I have no problem in ajax calls. @IGP

Comment: You should first identify which operation is taking time and then try to optimise it. You can try the following: 1) Optimise the DB Query. 2) Caching the DB Results to avoid repeated queries.

Comment: Caching might be a good idea if the results are always the same.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with your 2nd option but how will I catch the results after getting data from the database? @IGP

Comment: I am using native php in developing it :( @IGP

Comment: whoops, nevermind. I thought this was a laravel tagged question for some reason. If you're gonna use caching, then you're probably gonna need to read on redis and phpredis

Comment: @invalid-bot how will I perform option 2 in native php? I agree with it

Comment: All suggestions here are valid and could solve your problem. I think that the scenario of making a call to the DB when you display your modal is a fairly common one. It shouldn't slow down your DB unless you have a crazy query you're running. Once it runs and gives you the results, it's done. And if you're showing results for a single row, it should be a fairly small payload from the query. If your query is not performing well and you're using ajax and calling it many times then you could start to see a performance issue there.

Comment: The main problem that I must solve must be the performance when clicking the button and opening the modal continuously.

My query is performing well @PauloHgo

Comment: It's hard to imagine a scenario where you want to open several modals. Modals in Bootstrap are not the most elegant solutions and don't work very well in my experience when you need speed and performance out of them.

Comment: Yeah you have a point. Maybe I will really be making a page just for showing my data because I really do have many things that uses modal to show data. And I have a user that only checks data by just opening modal. @PauloHgo

Comment: @jEIZART // how will I perform option 2 in native php?
May be you can use Mysql-nd
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-qc.quickstart.concepts.php